# Is $x_{j} \bmod v$ dense in $[0,v]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Suppose that $(x_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an unbounded sequence inside $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a $v>0$ so that $x_{j} \bmod v$ is dense in $[0,v]$?

Note here that $a \bmod b := a- \lfloor \frac{a}{b}\rfloor b$.

$\textbf{Example}$: For the sequence $(j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$, $j \bmod \sqrt{2}$ is dense in $[0,\sqrt{2}]$.

I added the unbounded assertion as the sequence $((\frac{1}{2})^{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not dense modulo $v$ for any $v > 0$

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Added in the post.

Comment: I'm honestly perplexed by this question! All I have is a guess that the answer is "yes", but no idea how to approach either possible answer. Fwiw, it's easy to show that given any countable subset $V$ of $(0,\infty)$, there exists a sequence that's not dense modulo any element $v$ of $V$. But the construction certainly doesn't extend to $V=(0,\infty)$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such number $v$ always exists.

Notice that $a \text{ mod } b = \left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}b$. Therefore proving that $x_n \text{ mod } v$ dense in $[0,v]$ is the same as proving $\left\{\frac{x_n}{v}\right\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

$\textbf{Lemma}$. Let $V = [p, q]$ be a segment and $U = (\alpha, \beta)\subset [0,1]$ be an interval. Then there exist subsegment $\tilde V\subset V$  and $n\ge 0$ such that for every $v\in \tilde V$ we have $\displaystyle\left\{\frac{x_n}{v}\right\}\in U$.

$\textit{Proof}$. The assertion $\displaystyle\left\{\frac{x_n}{v}\right\}\in U$
can be rewritten as $x_n\in (v(N + \alpha), v(N + \beta))$ or
$$
v(N + \alpha) < x_n < v(N + \beta), \qquad \frac{x_n}{N + \beta} < v < \frac{x_n}{N + \alpha}
$$

for some integer $N$. For some large $M> 0$ we have $\displaystyle(M ,+\infty)\subset \bigcup_{N\ge 1}(p(N + \beta), q(N + \alpha))$. Since the sequence $x$ is unbounded, there is some $x_n\in (p(N + \beta), q(N + \alpha))$. Then $\displaystyle\tilde V = \left[\frac{x_n}{N + \beta}, \frac{x_n}{N + \alpha}\right]$ will do.

To solve the problem simply choose a sequence of intervals $U_k$ and iteratively construct a nested sequence $V_k$ using lemma. Any point in $\bigcap_{k\ge 1} V_k$ will be a solution.

Comment: $2 \mod 4$ is $2$ but $\{\frac{2}{4}\} = \frac{1}{2}$ so it is not necessary that $a \mod b = \{\frac{a}{b}\}$

Comment: You are right, thank you! I missed the part in a hurry, edited the post and now it should be correct

Comment: Does $\{ \frac{a}{b} \}$ denote the fractional part of $\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: Yes, i hope it is a common notation

Comment: I am convinced...but the proof needs more work.  For example you also need to say W.L.O.G assume that $x_{n} \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: So you have shown that each interval $[p,q]$ has a candidate $v$.

Comment: In this proof only the existence of large elements is needed, not the convergence to infinity.